# .Net Core Odata response missed metadata values

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, odata, .net-framework-version

Im using Odata on my old project with .NET Framework, and response from it like this:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "http://localhost:5000/api/$metadata#TestController",
    "@odata.count": 0,
    "value": []
}
```

Here is a metadata of odata and prop "value" contains response data.
But when I tried to install Odata into my new project on .NET Core 3.1, it works, but response from it like this:

```
{
   //some data
}
```

I haven't got odata metadata velues. I want that responses from all projects were similar. Can't find information how to add|turn on metadata into my .Net core response

Comment: Nope. In some cases I have odata metadata, but in some no.

Comment: You need to be sure set the whole entities in `GetEdmModel` mehod.

Answer (score 0):

It could work well in my asp.net core 3.1 project,here is a working demo like below:

1.Install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData` package version 7.5.2.

2.Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddOData();       
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication(); 
        
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.Select().Filter().OrderBy().Count().MaxTop(10);
        endpoints.MapODataRoute("api", "api", GetEdmModel());
    });
}
private IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    var odataBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    odataBuilder.EntitySet<WeatherForecast>("WeatherForecast");

    return odataBuilder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

3.Model:

```
public class WeatherForecast
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } //must have a key
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public int TemperatureC { get; set; }

    public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
    public string Summary { get; set; }
}
```

4.Controller(comment on `Route` attribute and `ApiController` attribute):

```
//[ApiController]
//[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    [EnableQuery]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>> GetAsync()
    {
        var rng = new Random();

        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]